# HTML Table Query not Sequence

Tags: html

I trying to query my html table but somehow it did not show correctly.
First row is correct.
Second row start from No.1,16/Sept/2020,36.5,Q1- Y,Q2- Y,Q3- YQ4- Y did not follow up the First row.
Please see my jsFiddle for better understanding.

```html
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=4>S/No.</td>        
        <td rowspan=6>Date</td>        
        <td rowspan=3>Temperature</td>
        <td colspan=4>Please answer the above 4 questions</td>
        <td rowspan=8>Submit</td>
        
    </tr>  
    
    <tr>
        <td >Q1</td>    
        <td >Q2</td>
        <td >Q3</td>
        <td >Q4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan=4>Y - Yes , N- No</td>      
    </tr>       
   
    <tr>
    <td>No 1</td>
    <td>16/Sept/2020</td>
    <td>36.5</td>
     <td>Q1- Y</td>
     <td>Q2- Y</td>
     <td>Q3- Y</td>
     <td>Q4- Y</td>   
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: How the table should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=3>S/No.</td>        
        <td rowspan=3>Date</td>        
        <td rowspan=3>Temperature</td>
        <td colspan=4>Please answer the above 4 questions</td>
        <td rowspan=4>Submit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Q1</td>    
        <td >Q2</td>
        <td >Q3</td>
        <td >Q4</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=4>Y - Yes , N- No</td>      
    </tr>       
    <tr>
      <td>No 1</td>
      <td>16/Sept/2020</td>
      <td>36.5</td>
      <td>Q1- Y</td>
      <td>Q2- Y</td>
      <td>Q3- Y</td>
      <td>Q4- Y</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```